# Need the children of an XPATH parent that has another specific children without direct correlation

Tags: html, xpath

I need to get a specific set of elements with XPATH. I need to get all spans that have the class objective as long as the ancestor div they're in has a children with the span class "objective-is-useful".

Unfortunately the spans are not direct children and they're contained among lots of containers in-between.

I attached an example like so:

```
<div class="superparent">
   <div class="parent">
     <div class="container">
       <span class="objective">Data 1</span>
     </div>
     <div class="key">
       <span class="objective-is-useful">Approved</span>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
     <div class="container">
       <span class="objective">Data 2</span>
     </div>
     <div class="key">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
     <div class="container">
       <span class="objective">Data 3</span>
     </div>
     <div class="key">
       <span class="objective-is-useful">Approved</span>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make an XPATH that'd return Data 1 and Data 3 but not Data 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
//div[.//span[@class="objective-is-useful"] and(@class="parent")]//span[@class="objective"]
```

Comment: This returns me all the span objectives (Data 1, Data 2 and Data 3) and I just need Data 1 and Data 3. I may have worded the example badly and I corrected it.

Comment: Seems it works with //div[*/span[@class="objective-is-useful"]]//span[@class="objective"], if you edit your question i can take it as accepted. Edit: Your edited answer also works. Accepted!

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry. I had to mention that the parent `div` has `parent` class

Comment: As an addendum, this accepted answer is better than my edit. My edit does not work on some parts, yours is better :D

Comment: Yup. My answer literally says: find `div` element with class name `parent` having some child element `//span[@class="objective-is-useful"]` in it. Now find `//span[@class="objective"]` child element of that parent `div` node.